# Proving $(1-x)\cdot (1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{n-1})=n$ if $x^n=1$ and $x\neq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If we have a equation $x^n=1$, then how can we prove

$$(1-x)\cdot (1-x^2)\cdots (1-x^{n-1})=n $$

when $x$ is not $1$? I know that $x= e^{(2\pi + 2k\pi)/n}$ and we can get different value of $x$ when $ k=0,1....,n-1$ but expanding our product will be a heavy task, is there any simpler way around?

Comment: If $x^n = 1$, then $(x^n -1) = 0$ so the whole product is $0$, so I think you may have done a typo.

Comment: You cant' bcause the product is clearly $0$ from the last factor

Comment: If $x=1$ this is false

Comment: Yeah corrected the typo

Comment: @Euler88... or more generally when $x$ is a non-primitive $n$th root of unity

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806636/question-on-primitive-roots-of-unity.

Comment: The equation in the heading and the equation in the question does not match.

Comment: They match now: I've corrected the title.

Answer (score 2):

If $\xi$ is any **primitive** $n$-th root of unity, we have:
$$ \frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(z-\xi^{k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-z \xi^k) \tag{1}$$
and the (right) claim follows from [De L'Hopital theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule), by computing $\lim_{z\to 1^-}$ of both sides.