# Find the sum of a series involving n roots of unity

Tags: summation, roots-of-unity

Given that $1,w,w^2,w^3,w^4.....w^{n-1}$ are nth roots of unity. find the sum of $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2-w^i}$$ The method I used was to write the equation of $w\;\text{as}\,z^n-1=0$ and further are writing this as $$z^n-1=(z-1)(z-w)(z-w^2)(z-w^3)....(z-w^{n-1})$$ and then replacing z here by 2. From this I was able to find out the denominator of the series in question but I couldn't figure out a way to simplify the numerator

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209034/finding-sum-k-0n-1-dfrac-alpha-k2-alpha-k-where-alpha-k-is-prim OR  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method different from those in the linked solutions.
Use the geometric series:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2-w^i}&=\frac12\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1-w^i/2}
=\frac12\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty\frac{w^{ij}}{2^j}=\frac n2\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{2^{kn}}=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2-w^i}=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}-1$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a simple trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative). Assume that
$$ p(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\zeta_k). $$
By applying $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides we get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-\zeta_k} = \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}.$$
In your case $p(z)=z^n-1=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\omega^k)$ and
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2-\omega^k} = \frac{p'(2)}{p(2)} = \frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.$$