# Weird sum of roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ 1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \omega_4\cdots \omega_n$ be the roots of the equation$$ x^n=1,$$ then find the value of

> $$\frac{1}{2-\omega_2} + \frac{1}{2-\omega_3}+ \frac{1}{2-\omega_4} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{2-\omega_n}$$
>   In terms of $ n$.

I tried many ways but was not able to solve this. If you see this message, then your question was automatically blocked by the server. All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for some basic indicators of a good, complete question. Check to make sure that your question has the following:

Comment: Since you said *you tried many ways to solve it* , would you mind sharing with us those ways and thoughts on this problem ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209034/finding-sum-k-0n-1-frac-alpha-k2-alpha-k-where-alpha-k-are-the OR  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity

Comment: The $\omega_i$ are roots of a polynomial of degree $n$. Can you find a polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are $1/(2-\omega_i)$?