# If $a_k=\cos(2k\pi/n)-2+i\sin(2k\pi/n)$, evaluate $a_1a_2\cdots a_n$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Define
$$a_k=\cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}-2+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}$$
How can I approach this product?
$$a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$$
I tried to investigate if one of terms is $0$, as it is a product, but no.

Any ideas?

---

I have already calculated this sum using the Euler formula.
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n,\;n>1$$

(original problem images: [$a_k$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHr8K.png), [product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnabK.png), [sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQeVU.png))

Comment: $e^{ix} = cos(x)+isin(x)$ and the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: Thank you @Paul. I resolved the sum, but I have some problems on some product of factors ;(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $a_k;1\le k \le n$

are the roots of $$(x+2)^n=1\iff x^n+\cdots+2^n-1=0$$

Using Vieta's formula $$\prod_{k=1}^n a_k=(-1)^n\cdot\dfrac{2^n-1}1$$

Comment: Great, I understand why you used the Veita's formula. Can you explain me how you knew the exact equation (x+2)^n by given roots?

Comment: @Akhtubir, $$a_k+2=?$$

Comment: You are great. I understand now, sorry for my language and for my little stupid question.