# If $\omega$ is nth root of unity evaluate $(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)...(1-\omega^{n-1})$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> If $1, \omega, \omega^2,..., \omega^{n-1}$ are the nth roots of unity then evaluate $(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)...(1-\omega^{n-1})$

I think there might be walkthrough solution somewhere for this, and I did find one tho. But the thing is the answer is not the same [Here is the link to the video I found](https://youtu.be/gDFQU7OjFpQ)

And here is my solution
\begin{equation}
z^n-1=(z-1)(z-\omega)...(z-\omega^{n-1})\\z^n-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1})\\\Rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (z-\omega^k)=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} z^m\\z=1\Rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\omega^k)=n
\end{equation}
Which the answer in the video say it equals to 0. Or perhaps $z$ can't not be equal 1? I'm very confused. Also in the video, why he picks $\omega^3$ why not $\omega$ or $\omega^2$?

Comment: That video is just nonsense.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: You say it is the nth root but in the video they say it is a cube root of unity

Comment: What did I just see ? -_-. Your approach is correct

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity/1909366#1909366