# Find the value of $(1−\alpha_1)(1−\alpha_2)\cdots(1−\alpha_n)$ in terms of $n$.

Tags: polynomials

Let the roots of $x^n −1 = 0$ be $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n$. Find the value of $(1−\alpha_1)(1−\alpha_2)\cdots(1−\alpha_n)$  in terms of $n$.

Comment: Hint: $(1 - x)^n - 1$ has roots $1 - \alpha_i$.

Comment: Hint: $1=\alpha_i$ for some $i$. But please provide more steps so that we can help you.

Comment: so 0, is that simply all?

Comment: Do you miss some conditions like $\alpha_i\ne1$?

Comment: no conditions given @Angae MT

Comment: Then that's all. Next time you should indicate your level of study so that we can discuss with the best language with you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity

Comment: It doesn't matter what the roots are, if a monic polynomial $p(x)$ has roots $\alpha_i$, then $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)\cdots(1-\alpha_n) =p(1)$.