# If $1,\omega,\omega^2,.....\omega^{n-1}$ are the n, $n^{th}$ roots of unity, then $(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)..(1-\omega^{n-1})$ equals?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$w^n=1$$
$$\omega^n-1=0$$
But $$\omega^n-1=(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)....(1-\omega^{n-1}$$because $\omega, \omega^2....$ are roots of the the equation $\omega^n-1$

So the answer should be zero. But the answer given is ‘n’. What’s going wrong?

Comment: Your equation is wrong. You are forgetting one of the $n$ roots on RHS. The given answer is also wrong. For  $n=2$ then product is $1-w$.

Comment: For $n=2$, $\omega=-1$, so the answer is still $n=2=1-(-1)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity/1909366#1909366  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806636/question-on-primitive-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $x^n-1$ has $n$ complex roots, given by the $n^{th}$ roots of unity, which are
$$
1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots,\omega^{n-1},
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Thus it has the factorization
$$
x^n-1=(x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)\ldots(x-\omega^{n-1}).
$$
If you substitute $x=1$ on both sides, you obtain $0=0$, since $x=1$ is a root. If you want to obtain a non-trivial product when $x=1$, you first need to get rid of the $x-1$ on both sides, like so:
$$
\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)\ldots(x-\omega^{n-1}).
$$
If you take the limit as $x\to 1$ in this equation you will find (using [this rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)) that
$$
n=(1-\omega)(1-\omega^2)\ldots(1-\omega^{n-1}).
$$

Comment: But the denominator is wrong. If $x=1$ then it becomes$ \frac 00$

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule to calculate the limit as $x\to 1$ on the left.

Comment: or you can use: $1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

Comment: Aditya, you might want to notice that the limit written in this answer is precisely the differentiation of $x^n$ at x=1.

Answer (score 0):

$x^n-1=(x-1)\cdots(x-w^{n-1})\implies x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1= \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}=(x-w)\cdots(x-w^{n-1})$.  Now plugging in $x=1$, we get $n$.

Answer (score 0):

y^n-1={1+y+y^2+…+y^(n--1)}(y-1)

then, (y-1)(y-ω)(y-ω^2)…{y-ω^(n-1)}=y^n-1={1+y+y^2+…+y^(n-1)}(y-1)
Now take y=x+1
Therefore x{x+(1-ω)}{x+(1-ω^2)}…[x+{1-ω^(n-1)}]
          ={1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2…+(x+1)^(n-1)}x

Comparing coefficients of x in both sides of the above identity

(1-ω)(1-ω^2)(1-ω^3)…{1-ω^(n-1)}=1+1+1+…upto n=n

Is it a proof?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).